# Python: Store a num in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google App Engine Python.

I would like to store a simple variable number somewhere, so I can add, deduct and use this number.

```
examplenum=5
example+=1
```

Next time I use this examplenum, it wil become 6.

I know I can build a `Model` and add an `IntegerProperty` varible. But I guess that would be too much hassle because I only need one simple number not a model.

I have also read this question [Simplest way to store a value in Google App Engine Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350454/simplest-way-to-store-a-value-in-google-app-engine-python), the `memcache` solution is not good for me. I want the number to stay forever not just temporary in the `memcache`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the answers to the question you linked are relevent to you. If you want persistance you will have to create a model. Look at using [get_or_insert](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html) to fetch/initialize an entity and give your entity a `key_name` so that you can keep fetching it easily whenever you need to store your values.

```
class MyAppData(db.Model):
    my_number = db.IntegerProperty()

# fetch entity whenever you need to store your value
data = MyAppData.get_or_insert(key_name='mydata', my_number=1)

data.my_number += 1
data.put()
```

You code does look suspiciously like a counter, and you might want to look at the [sharding countering](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) article and the problems that it solves in case they are relevent.

Comment: Hi Chris, I would like to know how to initialize your model? i.e. `data = MyAppData.get_or_insert(key_name='mydata', my_number=1)` It only has to be run once. I am thinking about a URL call and a function, I manually visit the URL once to invoke the function. Is there any simpler way? Thanks  alot!

Comment: that `get_or_insert` line can be thought of as initialisation. It will either fetch the latest version of the entity, or create one based on the other arguments.